# Pass and validate object to Vue 2 component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have Vue component with lot of props

```
<Field
        v-for="field in fields"
        :key="field.name"
        :name="field.name"
        :type="field.type"
        :label="field.label"
        :values="field.values"
        :value="field.value"
      />
```

I validate it this way

```
 props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'text'
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  values: [Object]
}
```

So, I want to pass all properties as one object eg

```
<Field
    v-for="field in fields"
    :key="field.name"
    :params="field"
  />
```

How can I validate and return default values for properties of this object?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43481866/7636961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Field
  v-for="field in fields"
  :key="field.name"
  v-bind="field"
/>
```

You can [bind an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) and each of its properties will be passed as props using the above syntax.